# Joda-Time return Wrong Date

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

Well Im using [Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

I want to convert the Georgian to Hijri date but it return the wrong date from georgian to hijri.

Im doing like this

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+05:00"); // Pakistan Time Zone
    DateTimeZone datetimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(timeZone);

    Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstance(datetimeZone);
    Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstance(datetimeZone);
    LocalDate todayGeorgian = new LocalDate(2014,04,13), iso); //Today's Date 
    LocalDate todayHijri = new LocalDate(todayGeorgian.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()), hijri);

        todayHijri.toString(); // This must return **1435-06-13** but returns 1435-06-12
```

Comment: is that related in anyway to the troubles people from old USSR satellites have to define themselves ? Georgian or muslim or ukrainian or russian speaking, etc  ? :P

Comment: no sorry, I had a look at the API and couldn't figure out the answer. The joke was not my best, I hope it was not offending.

Comment: The point Snicolas was making is that Georgian != Gregorian, basically.

Comment: Have you looked at IslamicChronology.LeapYearPattern? Perhaps you're using a different variant on the Hijri calendar to the default in Joda Time? (Having said that, using Noda Time they all give 1435-06-12, when using the Civil epoch, and 1435-06-13 when using the Astronomical epoch. I don't *think* Joda Time lets you pick epoch, unfortunately.)

Comment: No idea about this. but here in pakistan its 2014-04-13 is equivalent to 1435-06-13 but I m getting this 1435-06-12

Comment: Also this may be a probabilty issue.? @JonSkeet what u say. what is this?

Comment: @QadirHussain: I didn't mention anything about probability. I'm just saying that there are lots of variations to consider when you talk about "the Hijri calendar". (Aside from anything else, the fact that Gregorian days are midnight to midnight, but Hijri days are sunset to sunset confuses things...)

Comment: I'm now extra confused, as code that I *thought* would be the same under .NET's HijriCalendar and Noda Time's IslamicCalendar *isn't* the same. Checking...

Comment: ok- please help me regarding this. also is there any other API available to convert these dates?

Comment: @QadirHussain: You may just find you need to adjust all conversions by one day, I'm afraid. Noda Time allows you to specify the epoch, but I can't see any sign of that in the Joda Time API.

Comment: And then there is also the Um-alqura-calendar in Saudi-Arabia which is different from arithmetic hijri calendars and is not covered by JodaTime four leap year patterns. You should really make clear which variant of hijri calendar you are speaking about.

Answer (score 1):

Problem appears when you do redundant call of `LocalDate#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()` method.
`LocalDate` object is timezone independent, but when you convert it to `DateTime` (by `#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()` method ), it becomes zone dependent.
After it you convert `DateTime` to `LocalDate` again.
This conversions cause the issue.
Please, don't use `LocalDate#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()` here:

```
  Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstance(datetimeZone);
  Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstance(datetimeZone);
  LocalDate todayGeorgian = new LocalDate(2014, 04, 13, iso); //Today's Date 
  LocalDate todayHijri = new LocalDate(todayGeorgian, hijri);
```

**EDIT**
Also `"UTC+05:00"` is not valid zone for `TimeZone`. Use:

```
DateTimeZone datetimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+5");
```